# 2DTrigger Doesn't Destroy

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, 2d

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mrtMv.jpg)

I'm following a tutorial and the script of the coin doesn't work for me the coin should destroy when i collision with it

```
private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D collision)
{
    Destroy(gameObject);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Unity - Collision destroys objects.

```
 private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D collision)
 {
  if (collision.gameObject.name == "coin")
   {
        Debug.Log("Destroy" + collision.gameObject.name);
        Destroy(collision.gameObject);
    }
   
 }
```

Destroy the game object whose name is "coin".

Unity3d collides to destroy objects. You can refer to the following cases.Hope it helps you.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Destroy : MonoBehaviour {

private Transform m_transform;

// Use this for initialization
void Start () {
    m_transform = gameObject.GetComponent<Transform>();
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {
    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.A)) {
        m_transform.Translate(Vector3.left * 5 * Time.deltaTime);
    }
    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.D)) {
        m_transform.Translate(Vector3.right * 5 * Time.deltaTime);
    }
    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.W)) {
        m_transform.Translate(Vector3.forward * 5 * Time.deltaTime);
    }
    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.S)) {
        m_transform.Translate(Vector3.back * 5 * Time.deltaTime);
    }
}

void OnCollisionEnter(Collision other) {
    if (other.gameObject.name == "Cube") {
        Debug.Log("destroy" + other.gameObject.name);
        Destroy(other.gameObject);
    }
   }
 }
```

Comment: Can you upload an image of your scene with the game object you try to destroy+the inspector?

Answer (score 0):

the coin object have colider2d and isTrigge is on.
player object have rigidBody2d and box colider .
If you do these things it's work

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).